# Unexpected end of mysql in easyphp

Tags: php, easyphp

I have been trying to fix this error past couple of days.
I have to re-install easyphp if I need it...otherwise it would throw this error :-
Unexpected end of mysql...see log file ?

I've tried to change permissions by right clicking on the easyapache folder in program files(x86), still no luck.

Here's the log file : -

```
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-30 00:10:38 4a4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1607252 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-09-30 00:10:38 6704 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace graham/users uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\graham\users.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/innodb_table_stats which uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_table_stats.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_table_stats.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Need some suggestion to fix it.

Comment: The options available to you are listd in the log file, marked 1), 2) and 3). Start there.

Comment: Hi @MikeW I cannot find my.cnf file anywhere..any advice ?

Comment: For Windows the file is called `my.ini` (bad message from mySQL!) and you'll find it somewhere in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server\...` or one of its subsidiary folders. I don't know exactly where - I run Linux for my dev system. I'm assuming that easyPHP doesn't mess with the standard installation layout too much. You can always search for my.ini starting from the root of C:. It might take a while, though.

Comment: Tried all the above steps..no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the `my.ini` file located here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP5.2.10\mysql`.

As it mentioned on http://www.easyphp.org/faq.php#18